# How can I increase the damage a mob does in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a backrooms map in bedrock and I'm using the silverfish as a hitbox for the entity. Although the silverfish moves fast, it doesn't deal enough damage to the player. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't know how Bedrock differs, but you might be able to apply a strength potion effect to the enemy via command block.

Answer (score 1):

Give the entity strength with the `/effect` command.

```
/effect @e[tag=TagOfTheEntity] strength 99999 [Effect level 0-255] true
```

At the end of the command, change `true` to `false` if you want the player to be able see the effect particles.